# Надо синонимизировать метки [301] и [http-status-code-301]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки

- [301](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/301) (12 вопросов)
- [http-status-code-301](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-301) (27 вопросов)

[http-status-code-301](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-301) - главная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
updating post history, 13 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 12 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 11 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying '301': [301] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 38
tag remapping of [http-status-code-301] and [301] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```